# MongoDB Or PostGreSQL which will be better With Python Django and Express and Node js

Tags: python, django, node.js, mongodb, postgresql

As i am dealing with money like debiting from one account and crediting with other so for this work I think my database must strongly follow all ACID properties So for this work which will be more compatible MongoDB or Postgresql as i have read mongoDB does not follows ACID properties thats why i am confused.

Comment: can I ask you another reason for not considering MySQL? Anyways mongodb and postgresql differ on method of their storing of data. However Postgresql has started to support JSON data types now.

Comment: Because MySQL will be purely RDBMS but PostgreSql provides now document oriented approach thats why i thought why not just use the database which uses both RDMS (in terms of security ACID properties) as well as with document oriented also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SQL RDBMS is definitely your choice. If you are selecting between Mongo and PostgreSQL then PostgreSQL will be the answer.

As it's stated in Mongo official FAQ:

> MongoDB may not be a good fit for some applications. For example,
>   **applications that require complex transactions** (e.g., a double-entry **bookkeeping system**) and scan-oriented applications
>   that access large subsets of the data most of the time may not be a
>   good fit for MongoDB. MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for legacy
>   applications built around the relational data model and SQL.

Comment: What about ACID properties does MongoDB support ACID or not.